# thermal-hydro-mechanical (THM) coupling

Tags: multiphysics

Does anyone know good literature about thermal-hydro-mechanical (THM) coupling in Abaqus? In particular, I would like to know the theory behind the C3D8PT element. Thanks.

Comment: I am not well versed in the topic but I have found their theory guide very useful for my use cases, might be helpful! http://130.149.89.49:2080/v6.13/books/stm/default.htm?startat=ch02s08.html